# google-admin-sdk Directory User how to add custom fields using Java

Tags: java, google-admin-sdk

I am currently working on a project to update user details from our in house system and have a handle on the various information required to fill out the fields on a User object, however i am currently unable to set a custom field on the User object.

In this case i am creating a com.google.api.services.admin.directory.model.User object and have been able to persist the following fields

- Email Address
- User Phones
- User Relations 
  These are all persisting correctly with the latest updates back to the google directory, however i cannot find a way to set a custom field (Manager) from within my code.

I have also tried to use the UserCustomProperties object but cannot see how to add to the User object.

I have not been able to find an example of how to do this if possible could someone provide information on how to achieve this using the Java admin SDK.

Regards,

John

Comment: this may be related to this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28438758/how-to-set-user-manager-in-google-directory-api/28441715#comment45403752_28441715

Comment: Hi Gerardo,Thanks for linking to the previous query, in a way it is linked. but I'm still unclear as to what the process is to populate custom fields using the Java API.